# How do you return the total value of two methods that each take in a value?

Tags: java, class, methods

My teacher wanted us to create program to compute the bills of our home. In java we were just going over objects and classes so I made
class Bills{
Bills... etc

The problem I am having is I dont know how to get a total of two methods that take in a value.

```
public double getWifepay(double x){
return x;
}

public double getHusbandpay(double y){
return y;
}

public double getTotalmoney(){
???
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. What's the point of a method that simply returns its input?

Comment: So your `getWifePay` method takes x as parameter and just returns it? What's the point?

Comment: Mentioned later in the comments I forgot about setter methods. And also this is a partial copy from what we did in class......so.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your methods should probably just return some value that is stored within the object. So you would have something like:

```
public double getWifePay(){
    return wifePay;
}

public double getHusbandPay(){
    return husbandPay;
}
```

And

```
public double getTotalmoney(){
    return getWifePay() + getHusbandPay();
}
```

and then you probably would want to write some setter methods like:

```
public void setWifePay(double wifePay) {
    this.wifePay = wifePay;
}

public void setHusbandPay(double husbandPay) {
    this.husbandPay = husbandPay;
}
```

And in your class definition you should have declared these fields:

```
public class Bills {
    double wifePay;
    double husbandPay;

    // And then the methods from above
}
```

Comment: Ok I see. I forgot about my setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Create the previous two method (getwifepay, gethusbandpay) as static and call them in getTotalmoney function with class name. suppose class name is A so call as A.getwifePay(value)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your model classes, but as you mention, for the "getTotalMoney" method to return the sum, the elements (the numbers in this case) should be given as parameters.
On the other hand, your "getWifepay" and "getHusbandpay" methods don't make much sense, as they are returning the same parameter which is given.
With all of this, you would need to have the method "getTotalmoney" call the other two and then make the sum, like this:

```
public double getWifepay(){
  return x;
}

public double getHusbandpay(){
  return y;
}

public double getTotalmoney(){
  getWifepay() + getHusbandpay();
}
```

Finally, I suppose that these methods are within a given class (you mentioned Bill), making it maybe something like this:

```
class Bill {
  private double x;
  private double y;

  private double getWifepay(){
    return x;
  }

  private double getHusbandpay(){
    return y;
  }

  public double getTotalmoney(){
    getWifepay() + getHusbandpay();
  }
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.